# Typescript overrides .env file settings

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I have a Node Typescript project which uses `dotenv` and an `.env` file to set Node environment variables. There is a different `.env` file for development and production. They are very similar:

```
NODE_ENV="development"
SETTINGS=@jsondata/settings.development.json
TZ="America/Montreal"
SECRETS={ ... passwords, tokens, etc ...}
```

```
NODE_ENV="production"
SETTINGS=@jsondata/settings.production.json
TZ="America/Montreal"
SECRETS={ ... passwords, tokens, etc ...}
```

When I run `tsc`, it transpiles the project into the `/dist` folder, but in the build, the `.env` file is changed to this:

```
NODE_ENV="test"
SETTINGS=@jsondata/settings.test.json
TZ="America/Montreal"
SECRETS={ ... passwords, tokens, etc ...}
```

There's no code or setting in the project to replace `development` or `production` with `test`. This must be caused some setting of `tsc`, but so far I failed to find it.

Comment: Change ownership of that file and make it readonly, then check who and when tries to modify it.

Comment: It's my own local machine, and it's tsc changing it during build. This is the output. It doesn't change the original files, just replaces "production" or "development" with "test".

Comment: "and it's tsc changing it during build" --- this is hard to believe.

Comment: Well, that's what's happening. And it indeed makes no sense.